# Jquery: Is it possible to remove all the dynamically added text boxes together

Tags: jquery

> I have the following code that adds text boxes dynamically.

```
var counter = 1;
$("addBtn").click(function(){
    if (counter > 5) {
        alert('Only 5 text boxes allowed');
        return false;
    }

    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr('id', 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
    newTextBoxDiv.html('<input class="form-textbox" type="text" name="textbox[]" id="txt_brand_' + counter + '" value="">');

    newTextBoxDiv.insertAfter("#div5");

    counter++;
});
```

> The code below removes the textboxes one by one

```
$('removeBtn').click(function() {
    if (counter==1) {
        alert("No more textboxes to remove");
        return false;
    }
    counter--;
    $("#TextBoxDiv" + counter).remove();
});
```

> The above code works perfectly but I need to remove all the added textboxes at once and not one by one. Is it possible? Please help

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `IDs` you can use:

```
$("[id^='TextBoxDiv']").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure it's possible, for example add a css-class to them and then remove all with that class:

Modify this line to add custom css-class:

```
newTextBoxDiv.html('<input class="form-textbox my-dynamic-textbox" type="text" name="textbox[]" id="txt_brand_' + counter + '" value="">');
```

Then just remove all with that class:

```
$('removeBtn').click(function() {     
    $(".my-dynamic-textbox").remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a additional class to indicate it is added dynamically, then use it to delete

```
var counter = 1;
$("addBtn").click(function () {
    if (counter > 5) {
        alert('Only 5 text boxes allowed');
        return false;
    }

    var newTextBoxDiv = $('<div />', {
        id: 'TextBoxDiv' + counter,
        'class': 'dynamic-text'
    });
    newTextBoxDiv.html('<input class="form-textbox" type="text" name="textbox[]" id="txt_brand_' + counter + '" value="">');

    newTextBoxDiv.insertAfter("#div5");

    counter++;
});
```

then

```
$('.dynamic-text').remove()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add same class to the dynamically added element `say class='dynamic_element'`. Now when you click on the delete button remove element with the following class

```
$('.dynamic_element').remove();
```